# remove albums from music on iOS

Tags: ios, music

I have some music albums that while I want them, I don't want them to show on a specific device.

The albums are not downloaded to the device. So there songs are not on there, but the album covers still show.

How can I set it up so that the album covers for non downloaded music dont show on the device?

Comment: What iOS version?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Apple Music on your iphone to stop showing cloud purchases. Head into iPhone Settings > Music > Toggle Show Apple Music to off.